# Settings.Designer.cs file not updating automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, settings.settings

I have a Settings.Settings file and a Setting.Designer file. If I update/edit some settings in the Settings.Settings file, Its not being updated automatically in Settings.Designer.cs file.I am using VS2008. Any suggestions?

Comment: *How* are you editing them? Using the UI, or editing the file manually?

Comment: I tried using the designer view . The problem is I am using VS2008 on the server where the web application is stored and VS2010 on my computer. I tried the same procedure using VS2010 and It worked. The values were automatically updated in the Settings.Designer.cs file as well as the Web.Config file, but it didnt work for VS2008 .

Comment: I'm using VS2013 so I'm not that familiar with '08. What I advise is don't try to change settings by editing the Settings.Designer.cs. If you entered the setting using the Designer, make your adds/changes/deletes there as well. For more exotic settings, add a <appSettings> section to your App.config and then make your adds/changes/deletes there. Note 1: Settings mods made in App.config will *add* to the Settings Designer. Note 2: Changes to your custom <appSettings> in App.config will have no effect on the Designer.